# How to express $\sum_{i=0}^{m} \exp [(\frac{a}{b+c+i})^2] $ in terms of an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, power-series, euler-maclaurin

I have this sum
$$\sum_{i=0}^{m}  \exp [(\frac{a}{b+c+i})^2]    $$
where the upper limit $m$ is a finite non-negative integer, and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. I want to transform summation to an integral using the Euler–Maclaurin formula, or any other method if possible. How can I do this?

**P.S.** My major is not Math; searching on the internet, I see different versions of the Euler–Maclaurin formula that I do not know which one applies to my case.